# Auto adjusting Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have `div` which gets **auto adjust** with the `height` & `width` of the screen.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7s086tb/), and try to resize your browser, the `buttons` in the `div` will auto adjust themselves.

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  border: 0 !important;
  &:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
  &:hover {
    top: 2px;
  }
  &:active {
    top: 6px;
  }
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  .border-radius(10);
  .transition(all, 50ms, ease);
  .btn(rgb(204, 204, 204), 20%);
}

.btn(@color, @percent: 10%) {
  border: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px darken(@color, @percent);
  background-color: @color;
  .box-shadow(0px, 6px, 0px, darken(@color, @percent));
  &:hover {
    border: 0;
    background-color: lighten(@color, 5%) !important;
    .box-shadow(0px, 4px, 0px, darken(@color, @percent));
  }
  &:active {
    .box-shadow(inset, 0px, 3px, 0px, darken(@color, @percent));
  }
}

.position {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-container {
  height: 18%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="position">
  <div class="btn-container"><button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">PLAY</button></div>
  <div class="btn-container"><button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">SIGN IN</button></div>
  <div class="btn-container"><button class="btn btn-lg bg-primary">SETTINGS</button></div>
  <div class="btn-container"><button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">ABOUT</button></div>
</div>
```

I want to use that `div` in an `iframe`, but the *problem* is in `iframe` the `div` is *not auto adjusting* itself according to the browser size. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7s086tb/5/). (Only adjust when it is loaded, try to resize your browser after the page is loaded)

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="//jsfiddle.net/c7s086tb/embedded/result/" allowpaymentrequest allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: We do not want to go elsewhere. Your site will change and make this question no longer interesting. Please create a [mcve] HERE instead of pointing to an external unknown site that possibly is full of malware or shows adult content

Comment: I know, but it will be difficult to understand for experts by adding `JSFiddle`, I edited the links..

Comment: If you click the `<>` you can show code here too

Comment: @mplungjan I added the snippet too, but the second snippet is not working as expected...

Comment: At least people coming after will see the CSS

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, make the max-width of the button a percentage. Then it works. Now it is fixed to 250 pixels. Note that divs in the iframe do not inherit styles from the parent frame/window. You will have to declare this width inline in the div or in the head of the iframe... so NOT in the head of the parent frame.

```
.btn {max-width: 30%;}
```

Here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/c7s086tb/4/

Comment: And what about height? Last button is out of the browser when browser size gets small, (which force scrolling) & and I don't want scrolling...

Comment: `divs in the iframe do not inherit styles from the parent frame/window` but it is not inheriting the styles of the same frame...

Comment: You have put CSS in the fiddle with the iframe, but that does nothing.